# Change glyphicon color on row hover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am trying to change a glyphicon color when I hover the table row. The following CSS changes all of the other td's font color except the glyphicon.  I am using bootstrap 3.

CSS:

```
.table-custom-hover > tbody > tr:hover {
  background-color: #DD4814;
  color: #fff;
}
```

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></a></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this. Target `a` .

```
.table-custom-hover > tbody > tr:hover a, 
.table-custom-hover > tbody > tr:hover {
 background-color: #DD4814;
 color: #fff;
 }

<td><a href="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></a></td>
```

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thank you. I'll accept answer when timer expires.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<i>` for the icon and wrapped it with `<a>` this way:

```
<tr>
    <td a href="#">Test</td>
    <td><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></a></td> 
</tr>
```